Delete When Update Data in Dynamic Form Laravel
I have a dynamic form. I can update or create new data successfully, but when I try to delete a row, it shows an error

"Undefined array key "spec_name"".

How can I delete one or multiple rows when there's no data is updated/created and when there is updated/created data?

View
<form action="{{route('product-spec.delete',$spec->id)}}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
   <a href="" class="product-spec-remove text-color-danger float-end">Remove</a>
</form>

Controller
//update product specifications
foreach ($request->specifications as $key => $specs) {
        // Update
        if (isset($specs['id']) && $specs['id']) {
            $data = ProductSpecification::where('id',$specs['id'])->first();
            $data->product_id = $products->id;
            $data->spec_name = $specs['spec_name']; //the error is in this line
            $data->value = $specs['value'];
            $data->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        // Create
        } else {
            $data = new ProductSpecification();
            $data->product_id = $products->id;
            $data->spec_name = $specs['spec_name'];
            $data->value = $specs['value'];
            $data->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
        }
        $data->save();
}

public function deleteSpecification(string $id)
{
    $specifications = ProductSpecification::findOrFail($id);

    //delete specification
    $specifications->forceDelete();
}

EDIT
This is the edit form view code:
  <div class="col-sm-3-5 col-xl-4-5">
       <div class="product-spec-wrapper">
                                          
          @foreach($specifications as $i => $spec)

             <input type="hidden" name="specifications[{{$i}}][id]" value="{{$spec->id}}">
              <div class="form-group row justify-content-center product-spec-row pb-3">
                 <div class="col-xl-6">
                     <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-modern @error('spec_name') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Specification Name" name="specifications[{{$i}}][spec_name]" value="{{$spec->spec_name}}" />

                      <!--Error Message-->                                                     
                      @error('spec_name')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                           <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                      @enderror

                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xl-6">

                   <form action="{{route('product-spec.delete',$spec->id)}}" method="POST">
                      @csrf
                      @method('DELETE')
                        <a href="" class="product-spec-remove text-color-danger float-end">Remove</a>
                   </form>

                   <label class="control-label">Value(s)</label>
                   <textarea class="form-control form-control-modern @error('value') is-invalid @enderror" name="specifications[{{$i}}][value]" rows="4" placeholder="Enter some text">{{$spec->value}}</textarea>

                     <!--Error Message-->                                  
                     @error('value')
                       <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                         <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                       </span>
                     @enderror
               </div>
       </div>

      @endforeach

  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
     <div class="col-xl-9 text-end">
        <a href="#" class="product-spec-add-new btn btn-primary btn-px-4 btn-py-2">+ Add New</a>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>

EDIT 2:
I tried to update and create new data before doing dd($request->specification) and saving the updated/created data. As you can see in the image below, I edited one row (the "edit test" one) and added a new one called "add new," so I have three specifications for this product.

When I tried to do dd($request->specification), the result is something like this:
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => "19"
    "spec_name" => "edit test"
    "value" => "makanan edit"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => null
    "spec_name" => "add new"
    "value" => "new data"
  ]
]

The second data (Shelf Life) was not inserted into the array.
The controller works fine when I update old data, create new data without updating it, and create new data + update the old one. It's just not working when I try to do the delete process.

Your question is super unclear, you want to delete a row when updating it? Please add additional information to the questio so we know exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Please take a look at my form design first

@AmandaLinhan please share the code of the view (form) from which the update action is triggered.

@linktoahref already. Please help

Please dump the variable $request->specifications to check the contents. I think you might be getting the error when you are creating the product specifications in the else clause.

@linktoahref Hi, I edit the question to share the variable dump result. Please help. Thank you

Change the action value of the delete form to the following.
<form action="{{ route('product-spec.delete', ['id' => $spec->id]) }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
   <a href="" class="product-spec-remove text-color-danger float-end">Remove</a>
</form>

Assuming you have a route definition for the delete as the following:
Route::delete(
    '/specifications/{id}',
    [ProductSpecificationController::class, 'deleteSpecification']
);

References:

route helper method
Route parameters


Hi, I already tried your solution, but after I "submit" the form it goes to the blank page and doesn't delete the data from the database. Also, I couldn't dump the $specifications in deleteSpecification function's controller. It's just showing a blank white page

$specificationIds = array_filter(array_column($request->specification, 'id'), function($value) {return !empty($value);});

$specification = ProductSpecification::whereNotIn('id', $specificationIds)->get();
if(count($specification) > 0){
$specification->delete();
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Hi, your code is not working. It shows the same error. Can you give me more details on how to use your code (maybe I need to add some codes in my view, or something?) I appreciate your help
